# I want a function to only be allowed to call once a day

Tags: c#, vb.net

Let's say its the 15th and  my function runs, if that function is called again on the 15th it will not run. But if the date is the 16th and the function is called, then it is allowed to run.
How could I achieve this?
P.S. Code below is in visual basic however C# is fine for an answer

```
Private Sub CreateLogger()

    Logger = New CustomLogger(Sub(value, Type)
                                  Dim tempFileLogPath = IO.Path.Combine("C:\temp", $"FileAttributer_{Today:yyyyMMdd}.txt")
                                  Dim consoleLogger = New ConsoleLogger()
                                  Dim textFileLogger = New TextFileLogger(tempFileLogPath)
                                  Dim compositeLogger = New CompositeLogger(consoleLogger, textFileLogger)
                                  value = $"{DateTime.Now:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} - {value}"
                                  compositeLogger.Write(value, Type)
                              End Sub)

End Sub
```

Comment: There's nothing about a function that will prevent it being called at particular times. All you can do is store the last time it was executed and then compare the current time to that and return immediately if it's not at least a day ago.

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working?  In general the operation simply needs a way to determine if it has already been invoked "on that day".  How would you determine that?  What side-effect or information tells you?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose this has to do with the file, so in the end you do not end up with multiple files per day.

You could do a check on the file to see if it was created before or not.

Answer (score 2):

I would store the last called time in a variable, and update it every time you call it. It doesn't need to include the time of day, just the date. Every time you call the function, check if the last called time is equal to the current date, and if it is return/throw error to stop the rest of the function.

Comment: So after a reboot or after restart of the program I can run the function again?

Comment: @riffnl With this solution, when you call the function the first time, you should save the variable in a file or on the DB; when you reboot or restart the program, you should read the variable from where you saved it.

Comment: @allessandro - true, that would be a thing if that was in the answer, but it isn't - the answer is incomplete and lacking all good parts except for a brainfart

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the last run time somewhere and compare the day every time.

This is a very simple example how to do it:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
                    
public class Program
{
    private static DateTime lastRunTime;
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
            DoSomething();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
    
    private static void DoSomething() 
    {
        if (DateTime.Now.Day != lastRunTime.Day) {
            lastRunTime = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine($"Run: {lastRunTime}");
        }       
    }
}
```

But I guess, Radu Hatos is right. You should better explain, why do you want you function to behave so.

Comment: This approach allows you to run the function as many times as you restart the program or reboot the machine. Last run time should be saved on persistent storage such as a file or database IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple class like the one below to manage your calls.
(It is just a very simple example)

```
public abstract class ExecutionManager
{
    protected string ActionKey { get; }

    public ExecutionManager(string actionKey)
    {
        ActionKey = actionKey;
    }

    protected abstract DateTime GetLastExecution();

    protected abstract void SetLastExecution(DateTime dateTime);


    public void OncePerDay(Action action)
    {
        if (GetLastExecution().Date != DateTime.Now.Date)
        {
            SetLastExecution(DateTime.Now);
            action();
        }
    }
}
```

You would then implement this abstract class according to you needs: if you run the app on a single machine (console app for instance), you can implement a registry version or a file version to store the lats call dates / times.

If you run seveal instances on several servers, you will have to store the information in a database for instance, or a shared folder (there light be complex mutual exclision issues to manage here)

You will find below a very simple implementation with a file storage for the single computer scenario:

```
public class LADExecutionManager : ExecutionManager
{
    private static string FilePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "MyApplicationName");

    public LADExecutionManager(string actionKey) : base(actionKey)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(FilePath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(FilePath);
    }

    protected string FileName => Path.Combine(FilePath, $"{ActionKey}.txt");

    protected override DateTime GetLastExecution()
    {
        try
        {
            var sDate = File.ReadAllLines(FileName).First();
            return DateTime.Parse(sDate);
        }
        catch
        {
            return DateTime.MinValue;
        }
    }

    protected override void SetLastExecution(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        File.WriteAllLines(FileName, new string[] { dateTime.ToLongDateString() });
    }
}
```

To use these classes, you would code something like

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var em = new LADExecutionManager("MyActionKeyName");
        em.OncePerDay(() => MyAction());
    }

    public static void MyAction()
    {
        // Action...
        Debug.WriteLine("Executing Action");
    }
}
```

You just have to set an action key name in the constructor for each method (You could use reflection to get the method name but I think it is off topic here)